# Conflict during install cakephp/acl

Tags: windows, cakephp, acl

I'm windows user using powershell and want to install acl by composer.
I tried 
`composer require "cakephp/acl:0.6.0"`
and have this error logs

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[4.0.4, 3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev, 4.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev, 4.0.4].
    - cakephp/acl 0.6.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.8.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev].
    - Installation request for cakephp/acl 0.6.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/acl[0.6.0].
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp (locked at 4.0.4, required as ^4.0) -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.0.4].
```

my composer.joson looks like this.

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "https://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "^4.0",
        "cakephp/migrations": "^3.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.2",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cakephp/bake": "^2.0.3",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "~4.0.0",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "^4.0",
        "josegonzalez/dotenv": "^3.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
        "psy/psysh": "@stable"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "markstory/asset_compress": "An asset compression plugin which provides file concatenation and a flexible filter system for preprocessing and minification.",
        "dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper": "After baking your code, this keeps your annotations in sync with the code evolving from there on for maximum IDE and PHPStan/Psalm compatibility.",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "PHPStan focuses on finding errors in your code without actually running it. It catches whole classes of bugs even before you write tests for the code."
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-create-project-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Cake\\Composer\\Installer\\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump",
        "check": [
            "@test",
            "@cs-check"
        ],
        "cs-check": "phpcs --colors -p --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP src/ tests/",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf --colors --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP src/ tests/",
        "stan": "phpstan analyse src/",
        "test": "phpunit --colors=always"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I have no idea what that error talking about 3.x-dev and others X( 
If you need any other files to look or so please let me know : )
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is because you are trying to install a package intended for cakephp 3.8

Comment: @Salines then what should I have to do? find a package for 4.0 ?!

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/acl/tree/4.x try `composer require cakephp/acl:dev-4.x`

Comment: then I got this X( 
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package cakephp/acl in a version matching dev-4.x
require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...

Comment: Sorry, that branch is also for cakephp3

Answer (score 0):

When I check [github.com/cakephp/acl](https://github.com/cakephp/acl) I see in the right margin that the latest version is 0.7.0.
When I then run the composer call specifying that version, it installs without errors;

```
composer require "cakephp/acl:0.7.0"
```

So for future versions, I recommend checking github for the right version (latest, presumably, if you are working with the Cakephp version of that moment) and running this command accordingly.